# Upload file using ng-file-upload and mongo gridfs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, gridfs-stream

I want to upload a file that is more than 16MB to my database Mongo.
On the front end part, I use ng-file-upload module (https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload). On the back-end side, i use connect-busboy and gridfs-stream modules

I get the following error:
**POST /api/files/ 500 3.084 ms - 1992
Error: Unsupported content type: application/json;charset=utf-8
    at Busboy.parseHeaders (C:...\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:68:9)
    at new Busboy...**

When the file is selected, the function $scope.uploadFile($file) of my controller is called which is calling a backend server api with a post method. The issue seems to be on the api call part.

I have 2 questions:
- what am I doing wrong? and is there a better way to do it?

Here how my code looks like:

**front-end**

html page

```html
<label class="label-form" for="image">Upload Picture:</label>
<input type="file" id="image" name="image" ngf-select="uploadFile($files)" ngf-max-size="1MB" ng-model="image" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" accept="image/*" ngf-resize="{width: 100, height: 100}" />
```

then I have my controller.js

```js
var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', ['ngFileUpload']);

appControllers.controller('appUploadController',['$scope','$location','Upload', function($scope, $location, Upload){
  $scope.uploadFile = function($file) {
    Upload.upload($file)
      .then(function (resp) {
        console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
    }, function (resp) {
      console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
    }, function (evt) {
      var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
      console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
    });
   };
}]);
```

then my service.js file where the post api call to api/files/ is made:

var appServices = angular.module('appServices',[]);

```
appServices.factory('Upload',['$http',function($http){
    return{
        upload : function(file){
            return $http.post('/api/files/', file);
        }
    }
}]);
```

**Back-end**
Now on the backend-side, I have my app.js file, the api.js file and the database configuration file as below:

the api.js file:

```js
var Busboy = require('busboy');

app.post('/api/files',function(req,res,next){
  console.log("and the call has been successful");
  var busboy = new Busboy({
 headers: req.headers
  });

  busboy.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
  
  busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
    db.uploadFile(req.files.file.name); // call the function to use gridfs 
  });

  busboy.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('finish');
  });
 }
```

app.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var busboy = require('busboy');

var app = express();

var db = require('./app/config/database'); //load the config of the database mongolab
db.init(app);

// view engine setup - configure
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
 
// define middleware
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(busboy());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console

// define routes
require('./app/routes/routes')(app);
require('./app/api/api')(app, db);

app.listen(3000);
```

here is my database config file

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); //library for the mongo database
var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
var fs = require('fs');
var conn = mongoose.connection;

exports.init = function(app) {  
  //connection to the mongo database
  var  uri ="mongodb://...";
  Grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
  mongoose.connect(uri, {server:{auto_reconnect:true}});

  conn.once('open', function() {
    var gfs = Grid(conn.db);
    app.set('gridfs', gfs);
    console.log('connection open and the mongo db URI is' +uri);
  });
};

exports.uploadFile = function(file){
  var gfs = Grid(conn.db);
  var file_name = file.name;

  var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
        filename: file_name,
        mode:"w",
        content_type: part.mimetype
    });
   
    fs.createReadStream(url_image).pipe(writestream);
 
    writestream.on('close', function (file) {
        console.log(file.filename + 'Written To DB');
    });
};
```

Comment: In your html part you have specified 'ngf-max-size="1MB"' and you are uploading file of 16 MB

Comment: true, but i reuse the same function for all my files uploads so in this very specific first case, the file may be below the 16MB but I want to have one upload mechanism for all my file uploads.

Comment: how to modify the provided code for excel data dump to mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem with naming. Ng-file-upload use service name Update and you use your factory with name Update too and this is a problem - you use your factory to send file and this is a mistake.

You should use upload mechanism from Ng-file-upload, so remove your Upload Factory.

Your code will be look the same, because you use good naming, you add only url param;)

```
var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', ['ngFileUpload']);

appControllers.controller('appUploadController',['$scope','$location','Upload', function($scope, $location, Upload){
  $scope.uploadFile = function($file) {
   Upload.upload({
            url: 'api/files',
            data: {file: $file}
        })
      .then(function (resp) {
        console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
    }, function (resp) {
      console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
    }, function (evt) {
      var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
      console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
    });
   };
}]);
```